# Remove LARGE footer spacing on Portfolio site?

Tags: css

**How do I move the unnecessary spacing underneath the form in my footer?** I've tried everything.

The bigger the screen resolution gets, the **WIDER** that GAP/Spacing gets :/

I'm still learning to get better at coding so don't laugh!

Code:

```
  #form { margin-top: 80px; margin-left: 730px;}    

  #footer{ background: #311C68; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is to provide a reference for people who have the same question in the future. Asking us to fix a problem on one specific externally hosted website isn't what SO is for, and it's the reason "too localized" exists as a reason to close questions.

Comment: Sorry. I'm still new to the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `height: 100%` from `#footer`

```
#footer{ background: #311C68; width: 100%;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried that before. The only thing is a white spacing is at the bottom now. I did 100% so that every browser has the bottom footer color full.

Comment: forms.css > line 17 > `form ul:after, form li:after, form li div:after` contains a `visibility: hidden` - that causes the white stripe at the bottom. When you do `visibility: hidden` the element is not visible, but still takes up the space on the page. To fix that apply `display: none`